# In git, how to create a branch with commits from branch A, minus commits from B, plus commits from C?

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have a local branch called `local`, that tracks `origin.master` but has a few commits that help with debugging and that are meant to never be pushed.

When I work on a feature, I start my `feature` branch from `local`. Then, when it is ready to be pushed, I want to get rid of my local commits, hence I want:
`commits(feature) - commits(local) + commits(origin.master)`.

This looks a bit like a `git rebase`, but not quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done like this:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master local feature
```

Which is saying: Take commits from `feature` that are *not* in `local`, place them on top of `origin/master`

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly! Correct me if I'm wrong, but if we are already on `feature`, this is equivalent to `git rebase --onto origin/master local`. And (at least in my use case) it seems to be reversible by doing `git rebase local` (if that's of any use to anybody), although resetting to a commit from `git reflog` may be safer.

Comment: In hindsight my question is a bit lazy, the answer can be found [here, in the docs for `git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description), but maybe it can help people who don't know what to search for on Google, and happen to think in the same terms I do.

Comment: I particularly find this UI a little cumbersome.... like `git rebase master` vs `git rebase --onto master` vs `git rebase --onto master something` vs `git rebase --onto A B C`.

Comment: I've found that moving `--onto` to the end helps people understand the syntax better, so that the first two arguments don't change meaning, so `git rebase A B` is similar to `git rebase A B --onto C` except you change the reset point.

Comment: Good point @TTT, it does make things clearer this way!